# Static Google map (disable all gestures)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin

I want to create a Google Map widget which will not handle any clicks, gestures  - just a static map.
I understand I need somehow to set `gestureRecognizers` but can't figure out which class will lock all the gestures. What should I use instead of `ScaleGestureRecognizer()` ?

Setting `gestureRecognizers`to **null** doesn't help.

> When this set is empty or null, the map will only handle pointer events for gestures that were not claimed by any other gesture recognizer.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class StaticMap extends StatelessWidget {
  final CameraPosition cameraPosition;
  StaticMap(this.cameraPosition);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
      gestureRecognizers: {
        Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did my solution worked for you?

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu Yes, your solution works, I just ended up using `IgnorePointer(ignoring: false, ...)`. Was waiting a bit to see if maybe someone would suggest a way to disable the map actions by setting a custom `gestureRecognizers`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using **AbsorbPointer**

Make `GoogleMap` `child` of `AbsorbPointer` and set its `absorbing` property to `true`

```
return AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: true,
  child: GoogleMap(
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
    gestureRecognizers: {
    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
    }
  )
);
```

You can also set it's `absorbing` property `false` when you want to detect events

For more info on `AbsorbPointer` refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html)

Comment: I try on the web, and it's not working :(

Comment: Check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72273 this issue if related to your case

Answer (score 0):

For **web** & **iOS**, you might wanna try [pointer_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor) package by Flutter.

`PointerInterceptor` is a widget that prevents mouse events from being captured by an underlying `HtmlElementView` in web, or an underlying `PlatformView` on iOS. You just need to wrap the elements that are getting overlaid on top of the view in a `PointerInterceptor`, and their mouse will work as expected.

##### Example

Suppose this ElevatedButton is placed on top of Map in the Stack and you want to ignore pointers below this region. Just do it like this:

```
PointerInterceptor(
  child: ElevatedButton(...),
)
```

Related issue on Flutter repo: [[web] IgnorePointer or AbsorbPointer doesn't work with HtmlElementView on DomCanvas](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72273#issuecomment-747728199)