# How to check if the google map is moved by user gestures only (pan, tilt, pinch...) not programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, dart

The docs says

```
// Called when the camera starts moving.
  ///
  /// This can be initiated by the following:
  /// 1. Non-gesture animation initiated in response to user actions.
  ///    For example: zoom buttons, my location button, or marker clicks.
  /// 2. Programmatically initiated animation.
  /// 3. Camera motion initiated in response to user gestures on the map.
  ///    For example: pan, tilt, pinch to zoom, or rotate.
  final VoidCallback onCameraMoveStarted;
```

How to check if the map is moved by user gestures only (3) (pan, tilt, pinch...) not programmatically (1) and (2)

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/onCameraMove.html

Comment: This is called even if the camera was moved programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can track [taps and gestures](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures) and camera updates together and decide is map moved due to user gestures or not. Or even [disable gestures for map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536602/6950238) like [Mangaldeep Pannu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10471480/mangaldeep-pannu) proposed:

> ```
> return AbsorbPointer(
>   absorbing: true,
>   child: GoogleMap(
>     mapType: MapType.normal,
>     initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
>     gestureRecognizers: {
>     Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()),
>     }
>   )
> );
> ```

then process all of them programmatically and decide what to do with map.